# Connecting Amazon RDS to React & React Native

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, react-native, amazon-rds

I am running postgresql on amazon RDS but I'm confused on how to connect it to everything. I have a react application that communicates with the mobile app that is built on react native.

the react app is running nodejs but from all of the tutorials I am still confused on how to connect both the react app and the mobile app (RN) to the postgresql thats running on Amazon RDS.

Could someone please point me toward the right direction as I don't have anyone else to ask guidance from?

Comment: You can try using `graphql` with react. AWS wise you can use https://aws.amazon.com/de/appsync/ for that

Comment: So to make sure I have this understood. I can use graphql with react native to fetch data from my database which is on Amazon RDS and then on the backend I can also use graphql with react to send or edit data to my database, correct?

If so, can I replace the backend with graph cms so that would just replace the entire react backend admin UI?